# Estrutura do banco de dados para sistema de comentários

Tags: php

Em meu sistema (PHP), é permitido fazer postagens, que são salvas em uma tabela com suas respectivas informações: autor, hora, conteúdo, etc. Agora, estou pensando em colocar a opção de adicionar comentários à postagem, porém não tenho a mínima ideia de como ficaria a estrutura do banco de dados, se criaria uma tabela para todos os comentários da postagem ou sei lá, estou simplesmente **perdido**.

Alguém para dar uma luz em relação a isso?

**Obrigado!**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sendo o mais básico possível.

### Requisítos

Veja pelo seu própio requisito:

- **Você tem 1 postagem** (que consequentemente tem uma chave primária, vou chamala de id_postagem). Que resumidamente tem os atributos id, texto da postagem.
- **Você terá N comentários em uma postagem**. A postagem irá conter id_comentario, id_postagem (foreign key para Postagem) e comentário.

Logo, uma associação de **1 x N** (Uma postagem tem **N** comentários, sendo que N pode ser qualquer número).

### SQL

Para identificar a postagem:

```
SELECT * FROM postagem WHERE id_postagem = :numeroPostagem
```

Para identificar os comentários daquela postagem:

```
SELECT * FROM comentario WHERE id_postagem = :numeroPostagem
```

### Perguntas frequentes

**Se eu já tenho o id_postagem, por que criar um id para comentario (id_comentario) na tabela de comentários ?**

Para que seja possível identificar um comentário do outro.

**Por que eu tenho que levar o id da postagem (id_postagem) para a tabela de comentários ?**

Para conseguir identificar de qual postagem pertence aquele comentário

Comment: Acho que entendi a lógica... Bem, amanhã coloco em prática e então posto os resultados, caso de certo eu já coloco como melhor resposta, mas isso já foi de uma grande ajuda para abrir minha mente. Muito obrigado!